# Puppeteer viewport settings having no effect when creating PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, webautomation

I am trying to create a PDF using puppeteer. Setting viewport when creating PDF has not effect at all. However, viewport settings do apply for screenshots. There appear to be some issues identified on github in the past, but they were apparently closed out. Passing in defaultViewport: null was supposedly the solution.

Here is my code:

```
browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: null,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    headless: true,
});

let page = await browser.newPage();

// Set viewport
await page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 900, deviceScaleFactor: 2});

// Generate pdf
const doc = await page.pdf(options);
```

I also tried passing in viewport settings at launch.

Thanks!

Comment: Page viewport and the pdf output size are two separate things.  Try changing the size of your browser window and doing File -> Print.  You'll see it will have no affect on your printed document, but obviously it IS going to affect screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

`page.pdf` emulates a "Print to PDF" action. That means two things: First that [media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and second is that you need to pass an specific format or size to the `pdf` function.

From the [documentation](http://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.0/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions):

> The `width`, `height`, and `margin` options accept values labeled with units. Unlabeled values are treated as pixels.
>
> A few examples:
>    * `page.pdf({width: 100})` - prints with width set to 100 pixels.
>    * `page.pdf({width: '100px'})` - prints with width set to 100 pixels.
>    * `page.pdf({width: '10cm'})` - prints with width set to 10 centimeters.
>
> All possible units are:
>    *  `px` - pixel
>    * `in` - inch
>    * `cm` - centimeter
>    * `mm` - millimeter
>
> The `format` options are:
>    * `Letter`: 8.5in x 11in
>    * `Legal`: 8.5in x 14in
>    * `Tabloid`: 11in x 17in
>    * `Ledger`: 17in x 11in
>    * `A0`: 33.1in x 46.8in
>    * `A1`: 23.4in x 33.1in
>    * `A2`: 16.54in x 23.4in
>    * `A3`: 11.7in x 16.54in
>    * `A4`: 8.27in x 11.7in
>    * `A5`: 5.83in x 8.27in
>    * `A6`: 4.13in x 5.83in

Comment: Passing in the size to PDF options defines the PDF size which isn't my issue unfortunately. It's changing the viewport before rendering is the issue.

Comment: @drs I am having the same issue. I am not able to render pdf in desktop version. Did you find a solution. Please post it here if you did?